# NHibernate 3.1 Linq with Contains and Any

Tags: linq, nhibernate

We are in the process of upgrading to NH3.1 which is going well - 
everything is working as far as we can tell with existing code. One of 
the motivations to move to NH3 from 2 has been to leverage the Linq 
support and generally it is working really well. However I am 
struggling with some more complex where clauses, specifically when I 
want to check based on a sub-collection:

```
var results = from r in registrations 
              where ( 
                         from p in persons 
                         where p.ExplicitManagers.Any(m => m.Manager == manager) 
                         select p 
                     ).Contains(r.Registrant) 
              select r;
```

where the model is:
`p` is a `Person` and a `registration` `r` has a registrant of type `Person`
`p` contains a collection of `ExplicitManager` associative entities which 
hold a reference to another `Person` (manager).

note: registrations is an `IQueryable<Registration>.Query()` and persons 
in an `IQueryable<Person>.Query()`.
Essentially I am trying to restrict the registrations to where `person1` 
is an explicit manager of `p`. I can do this via joins but not through 
the `Contains` subquery.

I get the following error:

> "System.InvalidOperationException :
>   Sequence contains more than one 
>   matching element"

the reason for doing this as a sub-query is because ultimately I need 
to externalize the logic for checking the managers to make it reusable 
(it actually is more complex but I have simplified it for this example 
because it is the `Any` within a `Contains` which is causing the grief).

`Contains` seems to work fine when not having a sub-query with Any. 
Is this something I am doing wrong, or is it something unsupported or 
a bug, and is there another way of achieving the same thing?

Many thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whilst `Contains` doesn't seem to work properly, using `Any` does:

```
var results = from r in registrations 
              where ( 
                         from p in persons 
                         where p.ExplicitManagers.Any(m => m.Manager == manager) 
                         select p 
                     ).Any(p=>p == r.Registrant) 
              select r;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you execute the sub query on its own without problems?

```
var result = from p in persons 
where p.ExplicitManagers.Any(m => m.Manager == manager) 
select p;
```

Comment: Yes that works fine. It appears only to be an issue when the Any appears inside a subquery/'Contains'

Comment: Incidentally I have found the following works: var results = from r in registrations 
              where ( 
                         from p in persons 
                         where p.ExplicitManagers.Any(m => m.Manager == manager) 
                         select p 
                     ).Any(x=>x == r.Registrant) 
              select r;                                  which solves my immediate issue